# Removing the original color outline in R when using a new pallette in a barplot

Tags: r, phyloseq

I am using plot_bar function in R to illustrate some data from a phyloseq class. I want to add some different colors to my plot, here the pallette Paired from the RColorBrewer package. For some reasons the bars end up still having the default color around them. Here you can see how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBNYr.jpg
Any way I could get rid of them?

```
phylum.both.b <- plot_bar(both.b, fill="phylum") + 
  geom_bar(aes(color=phylum, fill=phylum), stat="identity")  + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0)) + 
  labs(x="", y="Relative abundance")  + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())  + 
  facet_wrap(~Type, scale="free_x", ncol=4) +
  facet_row(vars(Type), scales = 'free', space = 'free')
ggsave("PhylumBothBact.png", phylum.both.b, height=15, width=40, unit="cm")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined `color = phylum` in the creation of your plot, but never manually defined the color, so the default is still used. `fill` fills the bars with color in a bar plot and `color` outlines the bars.

Try adding `scale_color_manual(values = NA)`to your plot. Alternatively if you want the outline to match you could use `scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")`

Comment: As a side note, you can use `geom_col` which has `stat = identity` as the default, instead of needing to define `stat = "identity"` within `geom_bar`

Comment: Thank you so much! I added ```scale_color_brewer(palette = "Paired")``` to the plot and it worked! :D